# Multiply only numbers in a mixed string [VB.Net]

Tags: regex, vb.net

Let's say I have a string "N4NSD3MKF34MKMKFM53" and i want to multiply the string * 2 to get

N8NSD6MKF68MKMKFM106 How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: Tried multiplying the string  * 2

Comment: So, you have some code written. Would you share it with us?

Comment: You are going to need to split the string into its alphabetic and numeric parts, multiply each numeric part by 2, and then join the parts back together. Make an attempt at that and post your code.

Comment: I suspect, by your question, that you are a bit of a newbie, in which case I wouldn't recommend Regex.  But, if I'm wrong, I would suggest using `Regex.Replace`, using a custom `MatchEvaluator`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I might as well give you the Regex solution as long as I'm here.  But I caution you not to use it unless you understand what it's doing.  It's never a good idea to just copy and paste code that you don't fully understand.

```
Dim input As String = "N4NSD3MKF34MKMKFM53"
Dim output As String = Regex.Replace(
                                 input, 
                                 "\d+", 
                                 Function(x) (Integer.Parse(x.Value) * 2).ToString())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
Public Class Program
Public Shared Sub Main(args As String())

        Const  expression As String = "N4NSD3MKF34MKMKFM53"

        Dim  result = MultiplyExpression.Calculate(expression)
        Console.WriteLine(result)
    End Sub
End Class

Class MultiplyExpression
    Public Shared Function Calculate(expression As String) As String
        Dim result = String.Empty
        For  Each c In expression
            Dim num As Integer
            If Int32.TryParse(c.ToString(), num) Then
                result += (num * 2).ToString()
            Else
                result += c
            End If
        Next

        Return result
    End Function
End Class
```

Output: N8NSD6MKF68MKMKFM106